# Showing convexity of a function with the restriction over an arbitrary line

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n → \mathbb{R}_∞$ be a function and let $C ⊂ dom f$ be a convex set. 
$$**Part I**$$
**Prove that** $f$ is a convex function if and only if $f$ is convex over every line $L_{v,x_0}$ where $L_{v,x_0} := \{x_0 + tv : t \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

i.e. f is convex iff when restricted to any line, it be convex on that certain line.

So essentially to handle this proof I need to show that convexity for $f$ holds when its convex over any arbitrary line, and on the converse it does not hold when $f$ is not convex over that arbitrary line. If $f$ is convex then, 
$$\forall x,y \in C, a \in [0,1]$$ it holds that $$f(ax+(1-a)y) \leq af(x) + (1-a)f(y) \space \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space (1)$$

EDIT: $$**Part II**$$

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}_∞$ be a function.

I want to **prove that $f$ is convex over the line $L_{v,x_0}$ iff $\psi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_∞$**

$\psi(t) := f (x_0 + tv)$, is convex over $I (x_0, v )$.

where $L_{v,x_0}:= \{x_0 + tv : t ∈ \mathbb{R}\}$, and $I(x_0,v):=\{t \in \mathbb{R} : x_0 + tv \in C\}$

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: I'm afraid not; your negative case is wrong. You have *already asserted* that $C$ is a convex set. You will not find a pair of points such that $\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2\not\in C$, therefore. You should not be trying to disprove the convexity of the set $C$; you should be trying to disprove the convexity of the set $f$.

Comment: Your positive case needs work too. In particular, you have not mapped (1) to a line; that is, you haven't said what $x_0$ and $v$ are, and you haven't shown what affect the restriction to the line has on the domain.

Comment: Of course, your [other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109173/help-with-this-convex-set-proof) will help with that domain issue.

Comment: Wait, the way you've worded it, it's not clear what $C$ has to do with it. I was assuming that $C=\mathop{\textrm{dom}} f$; that $C$ *was* the domain of $f$. But you're saying $C\subset \mathop{\textrm{dom}} f$, which means its irrelevant to any proof of the convexity of $f$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I am not sure what you refer to when saying 'positive' and 'negative' cases? I thought I replied to this earlier, but apparently hadn't!

Comment: The positive case is the first---f is convex if it is convex along any line. And the negative case is the second---that f is non-convex if it is non-convex along any line.