# Help with this convex set proof

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Take $C ⊂ \mathbb{R}^n$ a convex set. Fix $x_0 ∈ C$ and a nonzero vector $v ∈ \mathbb{R}^n$ . Define the set $I(x_0,v) := \{t ∈ R : x_0 + tv ∈ C \}$. 
Prove that $I_(x_0,v)$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}$

My confusion arises from the fact that $I(x_0,v)$ is simply a line with direction $v$ passing through $x_0$. Since it's a subset of $C$ which is contained in $\mathbb{R}^n$ isn't it quite obvious that $I(x_0,v)$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}$ ?

How would one prove this?

edit:  My attempt
so I need to show that $I(x_0,v)$ is an interval. We do this by showing that for some $$t \in (a,b), x_0+tv \in C$$

Assume that $$x:=x_0 + av \in C$$ $$y:=x_0 + bv \in C$$

Because $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ is convex, $\forall x,y \in C, t \in [0,1]$
$$ tx + (1-t)y \in C$$

Is this on the right track?

Comment: Just because a set is a subset of a convex set doesn't mean that it's convex itself! $\mathbb{R}$ is convex, but not all of its subsets are convex. 

Also, your set $I(x_0,v)$ is $\textbf{not}$ a line with direction $v$ passing through $x_0$. Have a look at the definition again.

Comment: Do you mean $x_0$ instead of $x0$?

Comment: Thank you for the responses, I did indeed mean $x_0$.

Comment: Consider the set $C\in\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n~|~\|x\|>1\}$. It is clearly not a convex set; indeed, it is the *complement* of a convex set. Now let $x_0=0$ and $v$ be any non-zero vector. Then $I(x_0,v)=(-\infty,-1/\|v\|]\cup[1/\|v\|,+\infty)$. It's the union of two disjoint intervals. So no, it is *not* "quite obvious" that $I$ is a convex subset!

Comment: @elbarto I've responded to you in chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $I(x_0, v)$ actually is an interval. Intervals are convex subsets of $\mathbb R$. The only thing you really need to show is that $I(x_0, v)$ is an interval, i.e. if $\{a,b\}\subset I(x_0, v)$, so is $(a,b) \subset I(x_0,v)$. Do you have an idea how to do that?

---

To prove the statement you proceed in two steps:

- Let $I:= I(x_0, v)$. Assume $\{a,b\}\in I$, i.e.
  $$x := x_0 + av \in C\\
  y := x_0 + bv \in C$$
- Let $\alpha \in (a,b)$ be arbitrary. We must show $\alpha\in I$ or
  $$w := x_0 + \alpha v \in C$$
  To show this, write $w$ as a convex combination of $x$ and $y$, i.e. find a $\lambda\in (0,1)$ such that
  $$w = \lambda x + (1-\lambda) y$$

Comment: I didn't recognise from the way $I(x_0,v)$ was defined that it was an interval. 

So your last statement, if the set $\{a,b\} \subset I(x_0,v)$ then the points $(a,b) \subset I(x_0,v)$

To show this holds, I can just show that there is some arbitrary $x$ and $v$ which falls in $I(x_0,v)$ ?

Comment: No, but you must prove that if $x=x_0 + av \in C$ and $y = x_0 + bv \in C$, so is $x_0 + \alpha v$ for any $\alpha \in (a,b)$.

Comment: ahh right, I See. I'm sorry to pester you but I am still pretty new to proofs and haven't taken on any proof type units yet.

So if we assume $x=x_0 + av \in C$ and $y = x_0 + bv \in C$ then since $t\in \mathbb{R}$, $\forall t \in (a,b), x_0+tv \in C$ 

Is this a sufficient argument to show that $I(x_0,v)$ is classified as an interval?

Additionally, if you didn't mind I had one further question. Looking at the definition here, how did you distinguish the definition of $I(x_0,v)$ from a line and interval?

Comment: Not quite. You need to use the fact that $C$ is convex here. See that $I(x_0,v) = \{ t \in \mathbb R : \text{something}\}$ that means it's a subset of $\mathbb R$ now to see that it's an interval comes down to what you have to prove. I'm on my phone right now, but I can get back to you later if you still need more advice. I suggest you edit your attempt into the question so I can add criticism to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I would appreciate if you could get back to me when you'er available. I am editing my attempt as we speak.

Comment: @elbarto I added a general guideline for the proof. Maybe you can complete it like this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20343/discussion-between-elbarto-and-alexr).