# Convexity over a line given a convex interval

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}_∞$ be a function.

I want to **prove that $f$ is convex over the line $L_{v,x_0}$ iff $\psi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_∞$**

$\psi(t) := f (x_0 + tv)$, is convex over $I (x_0, v )$.

where $L_{v,x_0}:= \{x_0 + tv : t ∈ \mathbb{R}\}$, and $I(x_0,v):=\{t \in \mathbb{R} : x_0 + tv \in C\}$

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: Isn't this just a sub-problem for [this question here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109115/showing-convexity-of-a-function-with-the-restriction-over-an-arbitrary-line-proo)?

Comment: Ah thanks @MichaelGrant, I was unfamiliar with the rules of posting similar questions. Duly noted.

Comment: It's okay. If this is proving to be a key step in the larger proof that you are struggling with, go ahead at that other question and say so!

Comment: they were written as separate exercises in the text I'm using, so I had not seen it until much working up to it much later unfortunately.

Just curious, if I were to edit it into my old question now, would that bump my old thread up? Or would I need to rely on someone to search up my question again

Comment: I believe it would bump it in the queue.

Comment: Hi @MichaelGrant I was wondering If I could get any further assistance with either part of the questions, as I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: I do not. Honestly, I surmise that most practitioners accept the principles you've been asking about as true without having the proofs committed to memory. The proofs just aren't that helpful in practice. What you need, it seems to me, is the solution manual to whatever textbook you're going through. Now, if you *find* one, then you can answer your own questions, reproducing those proofs here---and we'd vote them up! :-)